# Is there a way to make the Swype keyboard (or any other) auto-switch back to the alphabetic keyset when I enter a punctuation mark?

Tags: swype

The question line pretty much says it all. Using the Swype keyboard (Galaxy Nexus, Jellybean, Swype 1.3.1.9410), is there some way/plugin/hack to make the keyset automatically switch back to the alphabetic/qwerty keyset when I enter a punctuation mark on one of the punctuation/non-alphabetic keyboards?